# Elastic Search - Field weight (for boosting) in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I know we can boost a field like this while making a search query in Elastic Search. Can we do this in mapping by giving a field extra weight?

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "likes",
                "factor": 1.2,
                "modifier": "sqrt",
                "missing": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using the [`boost` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) in your field declaration:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "likes": {
          "type": "integer",
          "boost": 1.2                  <--- add this
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw unrelated question but saying i will put id, name, country in an index but wont search in country field. If i don't specify the country field in mapping is there any harm or change?

Comment: No harm, by default the field will be created by ES automatically.

Comment: "type": {
                    "country": "keyword"
                } putting something like this will impede performance? Because maybe it will index it or something? If i don't specify anything it won't index the field?

Comment: If you don't want to index the field, just specify [`index: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html#mapping-index)

Comment: Great! another question is this. I won't search inside this "likes" field. But in name field. But if likes has more score will it automatically increase the "name" one. (They are in same doc)

Comment: because currently it doesn't boost anything.

Comment: Index time boosting is deprecated and not suggested.

Comment: If this question is solved, then we should just close it and create a new one, it's not a good practice to cram new questions into comments.

Answer (score 0):

Index time boosting boosting is deprecated in ElasticSearch 5.x and not suggested anymore.

If you want boosting just do it in search time.